# How to define DefaultScopedLifestyle in Simple Injector version 3.0.0?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I am working with dependency injection in a project using simple injector, and it works fine untill I needed to define a **lifestyle** when resolving a dependency in that particular version, **3.0.0**(I am using this version because I am using **visual studio 2010**).

In the official documentation, it says that I can define a lifestyle of a dependency using this line of code:

```
container.Register<IService, RealService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

But when I verify it, it tells me that I should define the DefaultScopeLifestyle, using this(or variations):

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
```

But in this version, I could not find the `AsyncScopedLifestyle` class or its variations.

How can I set the `DefaultScopeLifestyle`, or set it directly in a dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The v3 equivalent of `AsyncScopedLifestyle` is [ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/lifetimes.html#perexecutioncontextscope):

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle();
```

This lifestyle is located in the [SimpleInjector.Extensions.ExecutionContextScoping nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Extensions.ExecutionContextScoping).

This package requires you to run **.NET 4.5** or above.

If you are using **.NET 4.0**, you will have to use LifetimeScopeLifestyle/ThreadScopedLifestyle and run your operations synchronously or use WebRequestLifestyle in case you are building a web application.

You can find more information about LifetimeScope [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/lifetimes.html#perlifetimescope) and about ThreadScopedLifestyle [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/4.0/lifetimes.html#threadscoped).

Comment: To use the  `new ExecutionContextScope()` I have to download the SimpleInjector.Extensions.ExecutionContextScoping package from nuget right? But I am getting this error:


Could not install package 'SimpleInjector.Extensions.ExecutionContextScoping 3.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package d
oes not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework

Comment: Are these directly equivalent?

Comment: I've read it, and it really says that is an extension, and it is available in the nuget package. So I tried to install it, and got this error. I've also tried to execute this line with new ExecutionContextScope(), but it couldn't find this class.

Comment: Simple Injector's async support **requires .NET 4.5**. This holds for both the `ExecutionContextScope` in the SimpleInjector.Extensions.ExecutionContextScoping package of v3 and for the built-in `AsyncScopedLifestyle` of v4.

Comment: So, there is a problem, beacause I am using visual studio 2010, and it only allows me to use **.NET 4.0**. By the way, in older versions of `ExecutionContextScope` it does not required .NET 4.5, but I am still getting this error, in any older versions. There is any solution or workaround so I can use the ScopedLifestyle?

Comment: I'm sorry, but .NET 4.0 has never been supported for ExecutionContextScope.  You will have to use LifetimeScopeLifestyle/ThreadScopedLifestyle and run your operations synchronously or use WebRequestLifestyle in case you are building a web application.

Comment: You should seriously consider upgrading. Visual Studio 2017 community edition is free for small organizations. Nobody uses VS2010.

Comment: @William: You can find more information about LifetimeScope [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/lifetimes.html#perlifetimescope) and about ThreadScopedLifestyle [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/4.0/lifetimes.html#threadscoped).